# Scroll to newly added uitableviewcell ios 

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

I am adding rows to a table view dynamically using reload data. I need the table view to scroll with the newly added cell being on top of the view. In which event do I do this in and how ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick look [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) shows:

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You just tell it which row is new and it'll scroll to that.

Comment: I checked this function before. But I am not sure when to call it. Which event is called after a cell is newly added ?

Comment: No event is called when a cell is newly added. Presumably because you just added it and therefore know when it happened (and where it was added).

Comment: I am adding the cell using reload data. So all I do is add to an array and then call [tableview reloadData]. So I am not sure when this function returns.

Comment: If you're just adding a single row into an array, you might be better using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` than `reloadData`. You'd just do the insert and the scroll at the same time.

Comment: I managed to figure it out using the content offset of the parent table view. Thanks for your help.